# What type of RF connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

It is the silver connector in the photo. It has about a .25-inch inner diameter and is 50 ohms. It is too small to be mini-UHF. Thanks.

[image: photo of cable and connectors]

Comment: Does it mate to a BNC connector? Could be a slip-on (no bayonet).

Comment: I don't think it's a BNC.  I was guessing maybe some sort of GPO (Gilbert Push On).  But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I used this [Coax connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=coax_conn&o=microwave_conn&fl=00000000000000-0-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) to identify it as a [TS-9 male plug](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=coax_conn&o=microwave_conn&f=small_microwave_conn&s=TS-9).

For example, from [L-com](https://www.l-com.com/coaxial-ts-9-plug-crimp-connector).

"Disclosure: I created and run the Connector Identification Utility website linked in this answer"

Answer (score 0):

May be an RF coaxial cable, with an SMB female 90° and an F-type male push-on connector, used to connect a sat receiver to its antenna.

Comment: The left one could maybe be an SMB female but not so sure about the right one. SMB male are some 3.5mm diameter, it looks too big.

Comment: Thank you, @Lundin. I've edited my answer.

Comment: There's also something called "mini SMB" which looks quite similar but smaller. I can't tell from the pic - caliper time.